# How to create unique objects so that groovy set.add treats them as unique?

Tags: groovy

In the code below, I created two equal objects. However, when adding to set, it gets added twice. How do I ensure that set remains unique?

```
class Cell implements Comparable<Cell>{
    int x;
    int y;

    Cell(_x, _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    int compareTo(Cell cell){
        if (x == cell.x && y == cell.y)
            return 0;
        if (x <= cell.x)
            return -1;
        else 
            return 1;
    }
}

Cell cell = new Cell(1,0);
Cell sameCell = new Cell(1,0);
def setOfLiveCells = [] as Set

assert setOfLiveCells.add(cell) // cell is added
assert cell == sameCell // cell equals
assert ! setOfLiveCells.add(sameCell) //Shouldn't it return false? How to ensure set     adds only unique objects of Cell?
```

Thanks!

Regards,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `hashCode` and `equals`

With Groovy, you can do this with an [annotation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html):

```
@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
class Cell implements Comparable<Cell>{
    int x
    int y

    Cell(_x, _y){
        x = _x
        y = _y
    }

    int compareTo(Cell cell){
        x <=> cell.x ?: y <=> cell.y ?: 0
    }
}
```

You could also use the `Canonical` [transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html), and do away with your custom constructor (and gain a `toString` automatically):

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Cell implements Comparable<Cell>{
    int x
    int y

    int compareTo(Cell cell){
        x <=> cell.x ?: y <=> cell.y ?: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!! Learnt something new (Canonical transformation) again today :) btw should I use @groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode or  (import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode, @EqualsAndHashCode) method described [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html)

Comment: Oh and btw, i tried Canonical but it won't work for private fields. How do i make it work with private fields? thanks :)